# Can I snap windows to three columns?

Tags: gnome-shell

When I drag a window in Ubuntu 21.04 I can snap it to the left or right side of the screen (or by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>). Can this be configured to support three columns (e.g snap to middle), and two rows without a tiling manager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible on a vanilla installation.

If you are really not interested in a tiling window manager, I would suggest a GNOME extension called [WinTile](https://github.com/Fmstrat/wintile).

Comment: Thanks Pedro; this extension works perfectly for my use-case

Comment: I found that WinTile doesn't work out of the box for Ubuntu 22.04, but you can easily get it to work with [a tweak](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/z7afyw/comment/jeuihc4/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).